# Lambda cannot contain assignment

Tags: python, apache-spark

Tengo un texto y he extraído las palabras contenidas en él como sigue:

```
loremWordsRDD = loremRDD.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))
```

Ahora, estoy intentando responder a la siguiente pregunta:

*Cuál es la palabra de nueve letras que más se repite? Cuantas veces aparece?*

He escrito la siguiente linea:

```
loremWordsRDD_lon = loremWordsRDD.map(lambda word: (word,len(word))).filter(lambda t : t[1] = 9)
```

Quiero obtener un nuevo RDD del tipo (word,5),(word,9),(word,7) y luego filtrar si la longitud de la palabra és 9. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el código me dispara el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un error tonto en la comparación. La función lambda del filtro debería ser `t[1] == 9` en lugar de `t[1] = 9`, de ahí que te diga que no puedes hacer asignaciones.

Aprovecho la respuesta para mostrarte cómo se podría escribir eso mismo usando la sintaxis de comprensiones de listas, que es más compacta y para mi gusto más legible que la combinación de map/filter.

Sería así:

```
loremWordsRDD_lon = [ (word, len(word)) for word in loremWordsRDD if len(word) == 9]
```

En esta sintaxis, en lugar de primero hacer la lista con todos los pares y luego quedarse sólo con los de 9 letras, se crea la lista directamente sólo con las palabras de nueve letras.

Hay una ligera ineficiencia y es que se invoca `len(word)` dos veces (una para comprobar si se mete el elemento en la lista y otra para meterlo). Si te preocupa eso puedes hacer uso del operador *walrus* (`:=`) presente en python 3.8 (pero no en versiones previas). Ese operador te permite usar una asignación como parte de una expresión. Sería así:

```
loremWordsRDD_lon = [ (word, l_word) for word in loremWordsRDD if (l_word:=len(word)) == 9]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Sin embargo, al usar la lista de comprensiones me dispara el error TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable. Creo que debo usar el filter.